# Tomcat + managing properties files

Tags: tomcat, properties

We currently have one Tomcat server running 2 webapps; one for US sites, and another webapp specifically for the EU.  We have functionally partitioned the app & db along these lines; one logical instance for currently running US site, and another for the EU site.

Currently, our release process is as follows:
 - we deploy essentially 2 identical war's on Tomcat, except before re-starting tomcat we change a properties file to identify US, or EU webapp

What we'd like to do is automate this whole process.  I'd like to deploy my 2 wars, without modifying the properties files but also without really changing my build scripts very much.  Any suggestions for how to remove this manual step?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Ant build script you can use the `filterset` feature of the `copy` command to set the properties.
You need:

- a template property file
- two property files (one for each webapp)

Your template file:

```
...
locale = @deploy.locale@
other.stuff.int = 123
other.stuff.string = test string
...
```

(note the `@deploy.locale@` placeholder)

Your US property file:

```
...
deploy.locale = US
...
```

You EU property file:

```
...
deploy.locale = EU
....
```

In your Ant build file now you can:

1. wipe the TMP directory
2. compile the project into TMP directory
3. copy the template property file merging in the US properties
4. wrap up the TMP folder into war_for_us.war
5. copy the war_for_us.war in your tomcat webapps directory
6. copy the template property file merging in the EU properties
7. wrap up the TMP folder into war_for_eu.war
8. copy the war_for_eu.war in your tomcat webapps directory

You can also stop & start tomcat in the build script.
Here's how you copy the template:

```
<copy todir="${tmp.dir}" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="templates">
        <include name="template.properties" />
    </fileset>
    <filterset filtersfile="us.properties" />
</copy>
...
<copy todir="${tmp.dir}" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="templates">
        <include name="template.properties" />
    </fileset>
    <filterset filtersfile="eu.properties" />
</copy>
```

See [this post](http://babilsenior.blogspot.com/2010/01/deploy-scripts-ant-eng.html) for other Ant deploy tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it programmatically. First of all you have to implement aorg.apache.catalina.LifeCycleListener. It contains a single method

```
    /**
 * Acknowledge the occurrence of the specified event.
 *
 * @param event LifecycleEvent that has occurred
 */
public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event);
```

For the event parameter you have to listen context deployed events. You can look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html for some examples.

You will put the listener into the server.xml file of the Tomcat as

```
<Listener className="your implementation class name"/>
```

I hope it helps